# Python Loops and strings for CodeLab

Tags: python, string, loops

I cant seem to figure this out. Please help!

(Python)Given the strings s1 and s2 , not necessarily of the same length, create a new string consisting of alternating characters of s1 and s2 (that is, the first character of s1 followed by the first character of s2 , followed by the second character of s1 , followed by the second character of s2 , and so on. Once the end of either string is reached, no additional characters are added. For example, if s1 contained "abc" and s2 contained "uvwxyz" , then the new string should contain "aubvcw" . Assign the new string to the variable  s3.

Comment: How would you do it if the string were the same length?

Comment: Look at [zip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) and [for](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements), try writing an answer, and ask for more specific help if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
s3 = ''.join(s1[i]+s2[i] for i in range(0, min(len(s1), len(s2))))
```

In this way you mix two strings char by char. Loop is to min of length of this strings. So, if s1 > s2, range will be from 0 to len(s2) and if s1 < s2 range will be from 0 to len(s1).

It's same result like:

```
s3 = ''
for i in range(0, min(len(s1), len(s2))):
    s3 = s3 + s1[i] + s2[i]
```

but this is ugly. The first code is python style, and in python, the style is very important. We don't want to write ugly code :)

Comment: When answering a question, please take the time to add an explanation and why this fixes the problem. Code only is usually not very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Only code, but heavily commented...

```
# your strings
s1 = "abcdefg"
s2 = "zyxwvutsr"

# your new string, start with an empty one
s3 = ""

# the lenght of the input strings (yes, it's legal)
l1, l2 = len(s1), len(s2)

# find the shortest (MINimum) length
l0 = min(l1,l2)
# build s3 step by step, do you know about for loops, do you?
for i in range(l0):
    s3 = s3 + s1[i] + s2[i]
    print 'step %02d: s3 = "%s"' % (i, s3)

# and we can show the result of our zipping together the two strings
print '\nThe final value of s3 is "%s".' % (s3,)

####################################################################
#                    EXTRA PART - NOT REQUESTED
####################################################################
# Say we want to append to s3 the part of the longest string that
# was not appended, the "tail" of the longest string
if l1 >l2: tail = s1[l0:]
if l2 >l1: tail = s2[l0:]
# what is the meaning of, e.g., s2[l0:]? --- we denote a "slice",
# a part, of the string using two indices and a ":" colon, here the
# omitted second index means "up to the end of the string, refer to
# https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/introduction.html#strings
# for details

# That said, we have to consider another possibility, that
# the lengths are the same
if l1==l2: tail = ""

# we add the tail to s3 and output our result
s3 = s3+tail
print '\nThe final final value of s3 is "%s".' % (s3,)
```

#### Comment

For clarity I haven't used the idioms that a seasoned python programmer would use but rather the most straightforward expressions, however I have to mention that building a string in a loop is one thing that python does quite slowly. You can refer to any of the other answers to see how you can build a list of substrings and eventually join the substrings in the required result in a fraction of the time you'd use with the method I showed you.

Comment: From the OP: `Once the end of either string is reached, no additional characters are added.` So you don't need to worry about the tail.

Comment: I realize that you're trying to keep this code simple so that it's easy for a new Python programmer to understand, but in general doing `s3 = s3 + string_part` in a loop is _much_ slower than using a list to hold all the string parts and running `join()` on it at the end of the loop.

Comment: 1. I've read the Q, but I missed or misunderstood that passage! I'll edit my code to show the requested part and the extra part.  Thank you for drawing my attention.  2. Of course you're right on both points: I tried to stay extra simple and   building a list of strings is so much faster that it deserves a mention in the body of the answer (but I was late for dinner...)

Answer (score 0):

As Stuart suggested, the `zip()` function is perfect for this.

Although we can use indices to fetch the characters input strings, as in Simeon Popov's answer, it's considered more Pythonic to avoid using indices, when practical. We can do that because sequence objects in Python (eg lists, tuples and strings) are iterable, which means we can do things like

```
for c in my_string:
    print(c)
```

and it will print each character in `my_string`, one per line.

For your problem we need to iterate over a pair of objects in parallel, and the `zip()` function makes that easy. It creates a list of tuples of the elements of the iterables passed to it. The 1st tuple contains the 1st elements of each iterable, the 2nd tuple contains the 2nd elements of each iterable, etc; the list terminates when the shortest iterable is exhausted.

So

```
zip("abc", "uvwxyz")
```

returns

`[('a', 'u'), ('b', 'v'), ('c', 'w')]`

Now we just need to join all the pieces together correctly. :)

One way to do that is like this:

```
s1 = "abc"
s2 = "uvwxyz"

temp = []
for c1, c2 in zip(s1, s2):
    temp.append(c1 + c2)

s3 = ''.join(temp)
print(s3)
```

**output**

```
aubvcw
```

The loop joins the pairs of chars together into strings and stores them in the `temp` list. We then join the contents of that list into a single string using the string `.join()` method.

But we can do that more compactly using a list comprehension:

```
s1 = "abc"
s2 = "uvwxyz"
s3 = ''.join([c1 + c2 for c1, c2 in zip(s1, s2)])
print(s3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Almost there:
The zip operator does just what you want, like a zip irl it will match entries one by one until one of the vectors/strings finishes. Then just a list comprehension and a str.join should do the trick!

## Solution

```
s1 = 'bla'
s2 = 'blabla'
s3 = ''.join([x + y for x, y in zip(s1, s2)])  
# Returns: 'bbllaa'
```

#### zip

```
zip(s1, s2)
# Returns: [('b', 'b'), ('l', 'l'), ('a', 'a')]
```

Discarding the rest of s2 that has no correspondence in s1, which is what you wanted.

#### list comprehension

Now a simple list comprehension to 'join' all x's and y's

```
[x + y for x, y in zip(s1, s2)]
# Returns:  ['bb', 'll', 'aa']
```

#### ''.join()

Well, join will do what it says, joins a list of strings.

```
''.join(['bb', 'll', 'aa'])
# Returns: 'bbllaa'
```

So all together

```
''.join([x + y for x, y in zip(s1, s2)])
# Returns: 'bbllaa'
```